# Can I use constructor overload with RavenDB?

Tags: .net-core, ravendb

I had been trying to code a smart solution to my problem but I failed. I need to do a constructor overload in my identity, at my domain, first to an object instance and the other for RavenDB populate. It is not a big deal, right? But RavenDB doesn't work with more than one constructor, how the message show:

> Message = "Unable to find a constructor to use for type
>   Project.Domain.Business.Users.User. A class should either have a
>   default constructor, one constructor with arguments or a constructor
>   marked with the JsonConstructor attribute. Path 'Login'."

The idea is to keep inside my identity some domain rules which is necessary when someone makes an object instance. How we can see in follow examples:

My Identity User:

```
namespace Project.Domain.Business.Users
{
    public class User
    {
        public string Id { get; private set; }
        public string Login { get; private set; }
        public string Password { get; private set; }
        public string Role { get; private set; }
        public string Token { get; private set; }
        public string RecoveryToken { get; private set; }
        public string GoogleClientId { get; private set; }
        public string GoogleClientSecret { get; private set; }
        public string FacebookAppId { get; private set; }
        public string FacebookAppSecret { get; private set; }
        public Person Person { get; private set; }

        public User(string login, string password, string googleClientId, string googleClientSecret, string facebookAppId, string facebookAppSecret, Person person)
        {
            Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
            Login = login;
            Password = SecurityHolder.EncryptPassword(password);
            Role = "Common";
            Token = SecurityHolder.GetHash_HMACSHA256(login + "_" + password);
            RecoveryToken = SecurityHolder.GetHash_HMACSHA256(login);
            GoogleClientId = googleClientId;
            GoogleClientSecret = googleClientSecret;
            FacebookAppId = facebookAppId;
            FacebookAppSecret = facebookAppSecret;
            Person = person;
        }

    }
}
```

The object create in my service (or whatever, could be in the controller for example):

```
var emailObject = new Email(email);
            var cellPhoneNumberObject = new Phone(cellPhoneNumber);

            var naturalPerson = new NaturalPerson(name, gender, birth, emailObject, cellPhoneNumberObject, description);
            var user = new User(login, password, googleClientId, googleClientSecret, facebookAppId, facebookAppSecret, naturalPerson);

            var userResults = _userValidation.IsValid(user);

            if (userResults.IsValid)
            {
                _userRepository.Create(user);
            }
            else
            {
                throw new Exception(userResults.ToString("~"));
            }
```

I was thinking to use creational Design Pattern to create the instance of my object, maybe factory, and set identity atributes public. So, RavenDB should work fine too. But, I don't know if it is the right way.

**Edit:**

As Garay ask me. The create method are implemented in UserRepository:

```
public class UserRepository : IUserRepository
{
    private readonly IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork;

    public UserRepository(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork)
    {
        _unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
    }

    public User GetById(string id)
    {
        var session = _unitOfWork.OpenSession();
        return session.Load<User>(id);
    }

    public void Create(User user)
    {
        var session = _unitOfWork.OpenSession();
        session.Store(user);
        session.SaveChanges();
    }

    public void Edit(User user)
    {
        var session = _unitOfWork.OpenSession();
        session.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

The unit Of Work pattern has used to keep the raven state session as scoped. It is important to do users select and update in my services.

The unitOfWork code:

```
public class UnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork
{
    private readonly IDocumentStore _documentStore;
    private IDocumentSession _documentSession;

    public UnitOfWork(IDocumentStoreHolder documentStoreHolder)
    {
        _documentStore = documentStoreHolder.DocumentStore;
        _documentSession = null;
    }

    public IDocumentSession OpenSession()
    {
        return _documentSession ?? (_documentSession = _documentStore.OpenSession());
    }
}
```

Comment: The exception you stated is not from RavenDB , also I don't see any RavenDB client code.
RavenDB receives the initialized entity, it doesn't care what ctor was used to create it. 
What do you have in the Create() method?

Comment: Right, I will edit and show the create() method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution after some research. It is possible use the tag `[Json Constructor]` in constructor for RavenDB serialize this.

Example:

```
    [JsonConstructor]
    public User(string id, string login, string password, string role, string token, string recoveryToken, string googleClientId, string googleClientSecret, string facebookAppId, string facebookAppSecret, Person person)
    {
        Id = id;
        Login = login;
        Password = password;
        Role = role;
        Token = token;
        RecoveryToken = recoveryToken;
        GoogleClientId = googleClientId;
        GoogleClientSecret = googleClientSecret;
        FacebookAppId = facebookAppId;
        FacebookAppSecret = facebookAppSecret;
        Person = person;
    }
```

So, it has allowed to use constructor overload.

Read more in [RavenDb](https://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/2.5/csharp/client-api/advanced/custom-serialization) documentation.